# gatling: respons body not saving when polling http request

Tags: java, gatling

I'm running stress test using gatling and java, so when i poll http request, response body not saving, but when i call http request directly from `exec(getState)` without `poll()` function, it saves.
Here's my code:

```
    HttpRequestActionBuilder getState =
        http("Get state")
                .get(mainApiUrl + "/users/" + "#{" + INSTANCE_ID + "}")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + "#{" + AUTH_TOKEN + "}")
                .check(status().is(200), jsonPath("$.metadata.frontendStatus").saveAs(FRONTEND_STATUS));


    ChainBuilder startRequest =
        feed(randomRequestBodyFeeder)
                .pause(1)
                .exec(authorize)
                .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
                .exec(poll().every(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).exec(getState))
                .doIf(session -> session.getString(FRONTEND_STATUS).equals(WAITING_FOR_CUSTOMER_APPLICATION)).then(
                        exec(postApplication).pause(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                ))
                .exec(poll().stop());
```

Answer (score 2):

Polling doesn't support checks atm. This was missing from the documentation. I just [pushed a commit](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/commit/ac191e335b10c106a8f168172214535b978710d2) to mention it.

Then, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

`poll` works as a non-blocking background task.

It looks to me what you're trying to achieve is *"as long as the request doesn't return some status, wait some time and try again"*, hence some blocking logic.
This is something you should implement with a conditional loop such as `asLongAs` or `doWhile`, see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#aslongas.